# If applying for a federal (US) position through a talent finding service, how should my resume be formatted?

Tags: resume, job-search

Will the talent agency be expecting a one page resume, or the more detailed and information-rich federal resume format?

Comment: Have you checked if this agency indicates any requirements or gives any guidelines on how you should format your resume?

Comment: Now, the question you ask is something we can't possibly answer, as only that agency itself knows what kind of format they expect... please, consider editing your question to make it on topic, as in it's current form it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask them. If they have a requirement, or their customer has a requirement they will know it.

In the US there are no standards, there is plenty of advice but there are no absolute standards.

When we have put in a bid for federal contracts, I have seen a wide variety of requirements. I have seen word counts, font requirements, page requirements, margin requirements. I have seen requirements to how the dates should be formatted.

The person who wants your resume either has requirements or they don't, but you need to ask.